# Dropwizard AssetsBundle and Angular 2 path

Tags: angular, dropwizard

I am using dropwizard AssetsBundle serving Angular 2 application.
Now, angular 2 app path has following pattern:
http://host.com/base/route,
where http://host.com/base has to be rerouted to http://host.com/base/index.html, and "route" part to be parsed and handled by Angular client side code.

Unfortunately AssetsBundle can't find any resources by http://host.com/base/route path, and returns 404 error instead of rerouting request to http://host.com/base/index.html.

Any idea how to handle this?
I can write my own AssetsBundle to handle this situation, but would like to avoid it if there is any workaround.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the discussion at [Dropwizard usergroup](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dropwizard-user/a8Gikq_0wcg), it is possible to use IndexPageBundle plugin to achieve this:

Usergoup thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dropwizard-user/a8Gikq_0wcg

Code example: https://gitlab.com/linagora/petals-cockpit/blob/master/cockpit/src/main/java/org/ow2/petals/cockpit/PetalsCockpitApplication.java

```
@Override
public void initialize(@Nullable Bootstrap<PetalsCockpitConfiguration> bootstrap) {
    assert bootstrap != null;

    super.initialize(bootstrap);

    // TODO this is not the best because every new prefix must be added... if not, the static asset servlet will
    // take over instead of returning index.html
    // Improve when https://github.com/palantir/dropwizard-index-page/issues/38 is fixed
    bootstrap.addBundle(new IndexPageBundle("frontend/index.html",
            ImmutableSet.of("/", "/index.html", "/setup", "/login", "/workspaces", "/workspaces/*")));
    // no index file parameter because index is served by IndexPageBundle
    bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle("/frontend", "/", null));
}
```